# Circular file references are not allowed Dnn 7+ in TFS 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 7.3 for a website project which is a combination of VB and C# codes. I use visual studio 2013 to build the project. 
If the MSBuid Option in property page is configured to Allow this Precompiled site to be updatable and the project is published.
[image] There will be a successful built. But when it is checked in to the TFS, the following exception will be thrown:

```
 /compiled/DesktopModules/Admin/Security/manageusers.ascx (8): Circular file references are not allowed.
 /compiled/DesktopModules/Admin/Security/manageusers.ascx (67): Unknown server tag 'dnn:profile'.
 /compiled/DesktopModules/Admin/Security/EditUser.ascx (5): Circular file references are not allowed.
 /compiled/DesktopModules/Admin/Security/EditUser.ascx (163): Unknown server tag 'dnn:Profile'.
 /compiled/admin/Users/ViewProfile.ascx (4): Unknown server tag 'dnn:Profile'.
```

Also, when I checked Use Fixed Naming and Single Page Assemblies together with the Allow this Precompiled site to be updatable. it will throw:

```
ASPNETCOMPILER: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

when I searched online, I was given two options from [this blog](http://ellisweb.net/2009/12/fixing-the-circular-file-references-are-not-allowed-error-in-asp-net/).

I have tried the two but still having the same error.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed The Clean WorkSpace  property of TFS Build Process Parameters to false.
The error just disappeared and I was able to build successfully into TFS Drop folder. I don't know why this solves the problem but the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [here] (http://ellisweb.net/2009/12/fixing-the-circular-file-references-are-not-allowed-error-in-asp-net/) for the explanation why you would see this error, simply speaking, if you have the following setup:

```
/folder1/Control1.ascx > References Control2
/folder2/Control2.ascx > References Control3
/folder1/Control3.ascx
```

This means that the folder1 dll will reference the folder2 dll which will again reference the folder1 dll, causing a “circular file reference”.

The solution is try to rearrange all controls under each folders, sometimes, you have to make a problem user control copied over to multiple folders to prevent such circular calling.